# An error occurred during local report processing in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, rdlc

I want to generate `RDLC Report` on the basis of date. I have two `DateTimePickers` and a `Button` Controls on my `WindowForm` and a `ReportViewer`. I select from and To `Date` from `DateTimePicker`and When I click on a `Button` the `ReportViewer` should load from `Database` on the basis of `Date`.

Here is my `Stored Procedure`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetBikeSalebyDate
(
    @FromDate   DateTime,
    @ToDate     DateTime
)
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM tblSaleBike 
        WHERE DateOfPurchase BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
        ORDER BY DateOfPurchase asc
    END
```

and my `C#` code

```
        private void btnSearchBikeSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowReport();
    }

    private void ShowReport()
    {
        reportViewer1.Reset();
        DataTable dt = GetData(dtpSearchFromDate.Value.Date, dtpSearchToDate.Value.Date);
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"ReportSaleBikeByDate.rdlc";
        ReportParameter[] rParams = new ReportParameter[] {
            new ReportParameter("fromDate",dtpSearchFromDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()),
            new ReportParameter("toDate",dtpSearchToDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString())
        };
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rParams);//Error Occured Here
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }

    private DataTable GetData(DateTime fromDate , DateTime toDate)
    {
        DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetBikeSalebyDate",con);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fromDate;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = toDate;
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ad.Fill(dt);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

I have passed two parameters in `fromDate` and `toDate` in `ReportViewer`. When i put my program in a `debug mood`, and check the program and works fine i-e `DataTable` returns values correctly but when it reach to `SQL Parameters` it throws an `exception` `An error occurred during local report processing`. I don't know why because my `Report` is in the `root directory`.I am also going to attach the snapshots. Please help me out.

[image]
[image]

**Updated**

This is my `DataSet` which takes two parameters

[image]

and this is `Report Data`

[image]

and this is the `Exception Detail`

[image]

Comment: You need to share exception details.

Comment: Dear Sir i have updated my question. What details i am supposed to share?

Comment: The inner exception in details, helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Sir, The issue is now been resolved .. Problem with `reportViewer1.localReport.Refresh`. i have removed `LocalReport` and it solved for me..

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the following statement

```
        new ReportParameter("fromDate",dtpSearchFromDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()),
        new ReportParameter("toDate",dtpSearchToDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString())
```

The parameters must be written as they are in the stored procedure and you have take into consideration capital letters and small letters. The parameters should be as the following:

FromDate

ToDate